# How do I find col position of min value in excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 2*12 table ranging from cells A11:L12. I need to find the col number with the maximum and minimum number.

With the following formula I get the col number for maximum value:

```
=MAX((MAX($A$11:$L$12)=$A$11:$L$12)*COLS($A$11:$L$12))
```

but it did not work for MIN function (always return zero value). How can I fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For column with `MAX` value:

```
=AGGREGATE(14;6;(A1:L2=MAX(A1:L2))*COLUMN(A1:L2);1)
```

For column with `MIN` value:

```
=AGGREGATE(14;6;(1/(A1:L2=MIN(A1:L2)))*COLUMN(A1:L2);1)
```

[image]